# how do i call a function(controller) from xml in magento?

Tags: xml, action

this is my code: etc/adminhtml.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <menu>
        <attributegrouping translate="title">
            <title>Attribute Grouping</title>
            <sort_order>210</sort_order> 
            <children>
                <system_configuration translate="title" module="attributegrouping">
                    <title>Add new group</title>
                    <sort_order>20000</sort_order>
                    <action>attributegrouping/addgroup</action>
                </system_configuration>
            </children>
        </attributegrouping>
    </menu>
```

this is the etc/config.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Netgroup_Attributegrouping>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Netgroup_Attributegrouping>
    </modules>

    <global>
        <helpers>
          <attributegrouping>
            <class>Netgroup_Attributegrouping_Helper</class>
          </attributegrouping>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

this is the controllers/AddgroupController.php content:

```
<?php

class Netgroup_Attributegrouping_Adminhtml_AddgroupController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
        public function indexAction() 
        {
                echo 1;
        }

}
```

I want when i click on the "Add new group" in admin menu, to go to a controller function and display smth. in my case to the **indexAction** from class **Netgroup_Attributegrouping_Adminhtml_AddgroupController**. How should i do that ? thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `<action>` tag in your menu to

First add this in your `config.xml` as a sibling to the `<global>` tag. This will register your route.

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Netgroup_Attributegrouping before="Mage_Adminhtml">Netgroup_Attributegrouping_Adminhtml</Netgroup_Attributegrouping>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

Then change the `<action>` for your menu item from `adminhmtl.xml` to

```
<action>adminhtml/addgroup/index/</action>
```

And one more thing. Make sure the class `Netgroup_Attributegrouping_Adminhtml_AddgroupController` is located in `Netgroup/Attributegrouping/controllers/Adminhtml/AddgroupController.php`

Comment: what before="Mage_Adminhtml" does it mean ?

Comment: @Chester. It means that before looking for a controller in `Mage_Adminhtml` it will look for one in your module.